# Can all dependencies be in devDependencies?

Tags: reactjs, npm

Can all dependencies of a React-based website be declared as `devDependencies` instead of (production) `dependencies`?

Since the build folder is not versioned together with the code, each checkout of the repository will require a `build` operation to run the website. Thus every checkout can be considered a development environment.

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/specifying-dependencies-and-devdependencies-in-a-package-json-file 
No. You want the production dependencies to be in dependencies. Anything like test libraries, types, etc should go to devDependencies.

Comment: The proble for me is that, none of the packages meet the criteria of being required by the website in production. Because there is no way you will use npm on a production environment. Usually you will build the website and deploy the `build` folder.

Comment: Usually when you build for production, you want to skip the dev dependencies. Your production website doesn't need your testing libraries or anything else you need for development. That way you can keep your bundle size to minimum as you reduce redundant code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dependencies` is an object of dependencies that the app itself use, E.G `react`, `react-dom`.

On the other hand, `devDependencies` are dependencies that are only used when you're developing or building the package, E.G. `webpack`, `babel`, `prettier`.

Whether you need `npm install` in production or not, filling these fields appropriately will (at least) provide clarity for the readers.

Now answering your question, module bundlers and transpilers don't care whether the dependency is in `devDependencies` or `dependencies` or is it there in the first place. All it cares about that it exists in the `node_modules` folder.